# Android: Twitter oAuth Gives OAuthNotAuthorizedException Error

Tags: android, twitter-oauth

I want to use Twitter `oAuth`. I've looked different examples and tutorials. So I began from the outset. I've registered the application on `dev.twitter.com,` it's okay. Consumer Key and Consumer Secret are available.

Then I've added `signpost-core` and `signpost-commonhttp` jars to my libs folder and defined constans like this:

```
private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "myConsumerKey";
private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "myConsumerSecretKey";

private static String ACCESS_KEY = null;
private static String ACCESS_SECRET = null;

private static final String REQUEST_URL = "http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
private static final String AUTH_URL = "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
private static final String CALLBACK_URL = "OauthTwitter://twitter";
private static final String PREFERENCE_FILE = "twitter_oauth.prefs"

private static CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(
            CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
private static CommonsHttpOAuthProvider provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(
REQUEST_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, AUTH_URL);
```

And here is my manifest:

```
<data android:scheme="OauthTwitter" android:host="twitter"/>
```

Finally here is my click event:

```
try {
    String authURL = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, CALLBACK_URL);
    Log.d("OAuthTwitter", authURL);
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authURL)));
} catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I clicked the button I saw this trace:

```
07-23 06:24:48.428: W/System.err(15121): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException: Authorization failed (server replied with a 401). This can happen if the consumer key was not correct or the signatures did not match.
07-23 06:24:48.433: W/System.err(15121):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:243)
07-23 06:24:48.433: W/System.err(15121):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:193)
07-23 06:24:48.433: W/System.err(15121):    at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:74)
07-23 06:24:48.438: W/System.err(15121):    at com.exampel.app.MyActivity$1.onClick(MyActivity.java:71)
07-23 06:24:48.438: W/System.err(15121):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
07-23 06:24:48.438: W/System.err(15121):    at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
07-23 06:24:48.438: W/System.err(15121):    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
07-23 06:24:48.443: W/System.err(15121):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
07-23 06:24:48.443: W/System.err(15121):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-23 06:24:48.443: W/System.err(15121):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-23 06:24:48.448: W/System.err(15121):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-23 06:24:48.448: W/System.err(15121):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
07-23 06:24:48.448: W/System.err(15121):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1665)
07-23 06:24:48.448: W/System.err(15121):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
07-23 06:24:48.453: W/System.err(15121):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
07-23 06:24:48.453: W/System.err(15121):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1649)
07-23 06:24:48.453: W/System.err(15121):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1694)
07-23 06:24:48.458: W/System.err(15121):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-23 06:24:48.458: W/System.err(15121):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-23 06:24:48.458: W/System.err(15121):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-23 06:24:48.463: W/System.err(15121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-23 06:24:48.463: W/System.err(15121):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-23 06:24:48.463: W/System.err(15121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-23 06:24:48.463: W/System.err(15121):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-23 06:24:48.468: W/System.err(15121):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm sure about key and secret but still the same. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I must specify your code and answers are both looking fine, but not sure why not working. Elsewhere, I'm using `ConfigurationBuilder` while initializing `TwitterFactory`.

It looks like:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
    .setOAuthConsumerKey("ConsumerKey")
    .setOAuthConsumerSecret("ConsumerSecret");
try {
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();
    requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken("application://calback");
    WebView twitterSite = new WebView(MyActivity.this);
    twitterSite.loadUrl(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
    setContentView(twitterSite);                    
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then be careful about your `<data>` definition. The tag should be into `<intent-filter>`.

If still getting error, reset one more time. I hope this will solver your issue.

Answer (score 4):

reset key from twitter developer account and try again.. i have same problem and after reseting key problem solved.

use this url

```
 public static final String REQUEST_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
 public static final String ACCESS_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
 public static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";



public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-twitter";
 public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST  = "callback";
 public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL  = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
```

Comment: I've updated my code and still the same error. Anyway thank you.

Comment: it worked for me. after reseting key and change the new consumer key and secrets

Answer (score 1):

I used this on click for Twitter Authentication..

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrepareRequestTokenActivity.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
```

and this is the PrepareRequestTokenActivity.java

```
package com.twitter;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.WFBOS.SettingActivity;

/**
 * Prepares a OAuthConsumer and OAuthProvider 
 * 
 * OAuthConsumer is configured with the consumer key & consumer secret.
 * OAuthProvider is configured with the 3 OAuth endpoints.
 * 
 * Execute the OAuthRequestTokenTask to retrieve the request, and authorize the request.
 * 
 * After the request is authorized, a callback is made here.
 * 
 */
public class PrepareRequestTokenActivity extends Activity 
{

    final String TAG = getClass().getName();

    private OAuthConsumer consumer; 
    private OAuthProvider provider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try
        {
            this.consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constants1.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants1.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            this.provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(Constants1.REQUEST_URL,Constants1.ACCESS_URL,Constants1.AUTHORIZE_URL);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating consumer / provider",e);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Starting task to retrieve request token.");
        new OAuthRequestTokenTask(this,consumer,provider).execute();
    }

    /**
     * Called when the OAuthRequestTokenTask finishes (user has authorized the request token).
     * The callback URL will be intercepted here.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent); 
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Twitter", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(Constants1.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) 

        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Callback received : " + uri);
            Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving Access Token");
            new RetrieveAccessTokenTask(this,consumer,provider,prefs).execute(uri);
            finish();   
        }
    }

    public class RetrieveAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> 
    {

        private Context context;
        private OAuthProvider provider;
        private OAuthConsumer consumer;
        private SharedPreferences prefs;

        public RetrieveAccessTokenTask(Context context, OAuthConsumer consumer,OAuthProvider provider, SharedPreferences prefs)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.consumer = consumer;
            this.provider = provider;
            this.prefs=prefs;
        }


        /**
         * Retrieve the oauth_verifier, and store the oauth and oauth_token_secret 
         * for future API calls.
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Uri...params)
        {
            final Uri uri = params[0];
            final String oauth_verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            try 
            {
                provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, oauth_verifier);

                final Editor edit1 = prefs.edit();
                edit1.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, consumer.getToken());
                edit1.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, consumer.getTokenSecret());
                edit1.commit();

                String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");
                Log.d("toker", token);
                Log.d("Secret", secret);
                consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context,SettingActivity.class));

                //executeAfterAccessTokenRetrieval();

                Log.i(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieved");

            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieval Error", e);
            }

            return null;
        }


        /*private void executeAfterAccessTokenRetrieval()
        {
            String msg = getIntent().getExtras().getString("tweet_msg");
            try
            {
                TwitterUtils.sendTweet(prefs, msg);
            } 
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "OAuth - Error sending to Twitter", e);
            }
        }*/
    }   

}
```

and here is the  OAuthRequestTokenTask.java

```
package com.twitter;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * An asynchronous task that communicates with Twitter to 
 * retrieve a request token.
 * (OAuthGetRequestToken)
 * 
 * After receiving the request token from Twitter, 
 * pop a browser to the user to authorize the Request Token.
 * (OAuthAuthorizeToken)
 * 
 */
public class OAuthRequestTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{

    final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private Context context;
    private OAuthProvider provider;
    private OAuthConsumer consumer;

    /**
     * 
     * We pass the OAuth consumer and provider.
     * 
     * @param   context
     *          Required to be able to start the intent to launch the browser.
     * @param   provider
     *          The OAuthProvider object
     * @param   consumer
     *          The OAuthConsumer object
     */
    public OAuthRequestTokenTask(Context context,OAuthConsumer consumer,OAuthProvider provider)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.consumer = consumer;
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Retrieve the OAuth Request Token and present a browser to the user to authorize the token.
     * 
     */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {

        try
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving request token from Google servers");
            final String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, Constants1.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            Log.i(TAG, "Popping a browser with the authorize URL : " + url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error during OAUth retrieve request token", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

This is my Constants1.java

```
package com.twitter;

public class Constants1
{

    public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "your key";
    public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET= "your key";


    public static final String REQUEST_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    public static final String ACCESS_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
    public static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";

    public static final String  OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME   = "x-oauthflow-twitter";
    public static final String  OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST     = "callback";
    public static final String  OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL      = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;

    //public static final String    OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL      = "http://www.wfbos.com";

}
```

Comment: Thanks for details, but unfortunately still the same error. And I'm pretty sure about consumer strings, reset twice and tried many times. Checked out api status. Everything seems fine but I'm getting `oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException: Authorization failed (server replied with a 401). This can happen if the consumer key was not correct or the signatures did not match.` Not sure how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar code in place and was getting the same error.  I was able to get things working by setting my test phone to use the network's date/time settings.  Apparently if your device has incorrect date/time settings it can cause this issue.